# Find the point of intersection given their parametric equations, then find the equation of the plane they exist on.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, cross-product

The given is

Line $(1):$
$$x= 1+2t, \space y=4t, \space z= 3-3t$$
Line $(2):$
$$x= 2+t , y=-1-t , z=-3t$$

First I changed the variable in line $2$ to $s$ as to find the point of intersection of the $y$ coord.
$$y=4t=-1-s$$
$$s=-1-4t$$
Now we set $t=0$ to solve for $x$ and $z$
$$x=2+(-1-4(0))$$
$$x=1$$
$$z=-3(-1-4(0))$$
$$z=3$$
So our point of intersection is $(1,0,3)$ The $y$ coord being zero means that the intersection is parallel to the $xy$ and $zy$ planes.
So now we extrapolate out two vector from our given parametric equations
$$\vec V_1= \langle 2,4,-3\rangle$$
$$\vec V_2= \langle 1,-1,-3\rangle$$
$$\vec V_1 X \vec V_2=\langle-15,3,-6\rangle$$
So the equation of the line is
$$-15(x-1)+3(y)-6(z-3)=0$$
Am I correct?

Comment: How did you arrive at $V_2=(1,-1,-1)$?

Comment: Your right it should have been$(1,-1,-3)$

Comment: In the question, you write $y = -2 - t$ which seems a typo because that is not possible. In the working, you have used $-1 - t$ which seems fine.

Comment: your cross product seems wrong

Comment: Ok, I fixed the errors. How's the cross product looking?

Comment: Now it is alright

Comment: So all of it is correct?